# StoryBoard Too Late (Flip Navigation)

Tags: silverlight, storyboard

I have a Silverlight application with flip navigation which is composed of two storyboards that rotate the page and `To = 90, From = 0` and the other `From = -90, To = 0`.

The problem is that the second page contains many components (such as an image button, calendar, etc.). When you run it the first storyboard works well, but the second takes too long to start and this makes it look bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it an option to switch to silverlight 5 and use the [composition thread](http://weblogs.asp.net/sammueller/archive/2011/06/01/silverlight-5-animations-on-the-composition-thread.aspx)?

If not then you can try hooking on the Loaded event and starting the rotation animation there.

Comment: Hi Friend,     all the silverlight application is developed in 4, it seems best to do the second option you give me, I can give an example of how to link the event loaded with begin the storyboard